# filter records into another data extension

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

Is there a way to use the API to select (using a simple filter) and retrieve records residing in data extension (DE A) and update them into another data extension (DE B). I need to perform this action a couple of hundred times, so creating query activities in the UI doesn't seem like my best option. I have all of the names, keys and objectIds for the target DEs stored in a table so I was hoping to loop through the process. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation or code samples that addresses this type of scenario so I'm hoping someone here might have done something similar.

Thanks -

Mark

Comment: Hello, user6880, I'd love to help but unfortunately I am not very familiar with the Fuel SDK. Since ExactTarget is now part of salesforce.com, please promote the idea for an ExactTarget Developer Edition so that we can build a stronger ExactTarget presence here on Stack Exchange: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1yFAAQ

Comment: This is something I am pushing for @MartyC. In the meantime, I will continue getting other experts involved to answer questions. Thanks again for your interest in helping!

Comment: Are you basically trying to merge some DE's into one DE? Not sure exactly what the end goal is.

Comment: Hi Kelly  - I have a master subscriber DE where each subscriber has been assigned an identifier tied to a store location. For each store location I have built a DE to use within a Distributed Send instance. What I now need to do is get a copy of the subscribers that reside in the master DE into the appropriate DE for their location. As I mentioned in my initial post, there are many of these so I really don't want to create an individual query activity for each. I was hoping to figure out a way to accomplish this either directly through the API or through the use of AmpScript and API objects.

Comment: Any feedback on the answer below? Did you get it working?

Comment: Hi Kelly - The information helped point me in the right direction but I'm not sure how to bring the functions together.  I currently have php code that looks like the following:

Comment: require('ET_Client.php');
try { 

 $myclient = new ET_Client(); 
 
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$dataextensionrow = new ET_DataExtension_Row();
$dataextensionrow->authStub = $myclient;
$dataextensionrow->Name = 'Subscriber_Records_Master'; 
$dataextensionrow->filter = array('Property' => 'store_code','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => $row['StoreCode']);           
$dataextensionrow->props = array('email_address', 'name_first', $name_last','store_code','member_id','birthday'); 
$response = $dataextensionrow->get();

Comment: $dataextension = new ET_DataExtension();
$dataextension->authStub = $myclient;
$dataextension->props = array("CustomerKey" => $row['StoreCode'],"Name" => $row['DE_Name'],$response['email_address'],$response['name_first'],$response['name_last'],['store_code'],['member_id'], $response['birthday']);
$results = $dataextension->patch();

Comment: I am populating Customer Key, Name and StoreCode from a database table.  What I need to be able to do is take the results from the get request and use that data to populate the patch request and then loop through that for each of the records in the database table.  I am a newbie at this so I apologize if there's something obvious that I'm missing but if I try to execute the code I am getting the following error: Cannot use object of type ET_Get as array

Comment: Any assistance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (Also, apologies for having to break this up into several posts. The character limit on this site is a disadvantage from the @Code site.)

Answer (score 1):

Mark,

This would be possible using the API.

Retrieve: https://code.exacttarget.com/sdks/fuel-sdk-interacting-data-extension-rows#Retrieving

Update: https://code.exacttarget.com/sdks/fuel-sdk-interacting-data-extension#Updating

It would also be possible to filter Subscribers with the  Distributed Sending account settings. I am assuming that there is a specific reason that you are not using the Subscriber model, but it is very simple to set up.

If there is data you needed to protect about subscribers you can have that held by Subscriber Key in a DE at the Enterprise level. AMP Script can access those DEs with "ent.DE_NAME" in a lookup function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and information, Caleb. Not exactly sure what you meant by Subscriber Model though. We have several child BUs under a parent BU (which is a child of the enterprise level account). However, within those child business units we will be using distributed sending.  I know that we can filter subscribers from the enterprise into specific BUs but that isn't the use case here and I'm not sure of how you would filter subscribers within Distributed Sending itself? As far as I know Distributed Sending is really just a UI and user role modification that sits on top of a BU?

Comment: Caleb, the link you provided for Updating will update the actual DE info, such as the name. I believe what Mark P needs to do is actually insert new rows into a DE based on the results of the retrieve.

Creating a new row: https://code.exacttarget.com/sdks/fuel-sdk-interacting-data-extension-rows#Creating